# Is it possible to root a Verizon LG G4?

Tags: rooting, root-access, lg, verizon, lg-g4

Is it possible to root a Verizon LG G4?

I've done quite a bit of research, and have found that it is definitely possible to root a non-Verizon LG G4, but I have not found any way to root the Verizon model.

Prefer solutions not using KingRoot.

Comment: Sympathy to users of Verizon devices.

Comment: @AndyYan Are Verizon devices known to be more difficult to root?

Comment: Certainly, along with AT&T. Locked down bootloaders and stuff.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks.  If you find (or anyone else finds) a solution, please do post.